# Bootstrap Modal Box does not fit properly to browsersize

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, slider

I have fiddeled around with my modal img slider from bootstrap for weeks now- I have got it kinda working now - with a wobble and some cropping when the window goes sm/xs.. wondering weather it's possible to resize the img slider and the modal box so the img is always at the max. width/height it can get leaving a little space to all sides 
the other problem is, that I might have changed anything in my code.. because since I've tried to fix the modal, the modal does not collapse any more when I just click on the grey background, the only way to let it collapse is to click the close button. 
And the marquee does stop running after a while since then, too

Appart of the Bootsrtap css and jquery I used that code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Anton Hörl, München Skulpturen und Grafiken</title>
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <meta content="" name="description">        
    <meta content="index,follow" name="robots">
    <meta content="" name="author">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/zeichnungen.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />


</head>

<body>
     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>


    <marquee scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="1"> nächste Ausstellung am...</marquee>
<!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <li class="active"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Bilder/grafik4.jpg" type="picture/jpg"/></a></li>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="#">Figuren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Zeichnungen</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Vita</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Englisch</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Kontakt und Impressum<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">A.H</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Webseitengestaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Foto und Film</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Copyright 2014</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!--NAVBAR ENDE-->


    <div class="container"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <div class="row">
        <h1>Zeichnungen</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 1" href="#"data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="0"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive active" src="Zeichnungen/1.jpg"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 2" href="#"data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="1"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/2.jpg"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 3" href="#"data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="2"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/3.jpg"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 4" href="#"data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="3"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/4.jpg"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 5" href="#"data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="4"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/5.jpg"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 6" href="#"data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="5"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/6.jpg"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 7" href="#"data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="6"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/7.jpg"></a></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 8" href="#"data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="7"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/8.jpg"></a></div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade container" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog-row row">
          <div class="modal-content col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-7 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-5">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active" title="Image 1">
                                <h3 class="modal-title">Image 1</h3>
                                <a href="#" title="Image 1"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/1.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item " title="Image 2">
                                <h3 class="modal-title">Image 2</h3>
                                <a href="#" title="Image 2">
                                    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/2.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" title="Image 3"><h3 class="modal-title">Image 3</h3>
                                <a href="#" title="Image 3">
                                    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/3.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" title="Image 4"><h3 class="modal-title">Image 4</h3>
                                <a href="#" title="Image 4">
                                    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/4.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" title="Image 5"><h3 class="modal-title">Image 5</h3>
                                <a href="#" title="Image 5">
                                    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/5.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" title="Image 6"><h3 class="modal-title">Image 6</h3><p class="modal-title">Größe:</p>
                                <a href="#" title="Image 6">
                                    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/6.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" title="Image 7"><h3 class="modal-title">Image 7</h3>
                                <a href="#" title="Image 7">
                                    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/7.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" title="Image 8"><h3 class="modal-title">Image 8</h3>
                                <a href="#" title="Image 8">
                                    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive"Style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin-top:25%;" src="Zeichnungen/8.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"src="Bilder/arror left.gif"Style="width: 95%; height: auto;transform: translate(5%); margin-top:50%;"></i></a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"src="Bilder/arror right.gif"Style="width: 95%; height: auto;transform: translate(5%); margin-top:50%;"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
```

```
        .thumbnail {margin-bottom:10px;}
    .modal-header {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .modal-body {
        max-height: 95% !important;
        max-width: 95% !important;
        padding: 20px !important;

    }
    .modal-dialog-row {
        z-index:1050;
        right:auto;
        padding:10px;
        padding-top:30px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    .modal-content {
        background-clip: padding-box;
        background-color: transparent !important;
        border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
        border-radius: 0px !important;
        box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)!important;
        outline: medium none;
        position: relative;
        text-align:center;
        color: white;
    }


    .carousel-inner > .item > img, 
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        line-height: 1;

    }

    .carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
      background-image:none;
      margin-top:5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
      width:5%;
    }

    .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
     .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, 
     .carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next {
        margin-left: 10px !important;
        margin-right: -15px !important;   
    }
    button.btn-default {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white!important;
        border: 10px none!important;
        border-radius: 20px !important;
        color: grey!important;
        height: 30px!important;
        margin-right: 10px !important;
        width: 30px!important;

    }
    .btn-default  {
        color: grey!important;
        font-size: 45px!important;
        line-height: 0!important;
        opacity: 1!important;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(145, 168, 129, 1)!important;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to make a lightbox? Something like this? http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-lightbox/

Comment: yeees exactely like the secound one.. :) is that possible to build with bootstrap???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to implement a lightbox using just the default Bootstrap files. Sure you could build it in customly but why reinvent the wheel? My suggestion is to use a plugin that someone has already created.

Some suggestions:

[Nivo Lightbox](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-lightbox/) is a great lightbox and has a MIT license. It has a very slight css compatibility issue with Bootstrap (to do with box-sizing: border-box) but that is very easy to fix.

[Bootstrap 3 Lightbox](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/). I've never actually used this but it seems to be able to do what you are wanting. Has a GNU General Public License.

Comment: Thx a lot.. 
I tryed to avoid any plugins, becouse as I tried to use one once I needed to build the whole page new as I somehow managed to muck up the whole code... - since then I try to use as less plugins as possible.. :)
But as the lightbox is for bootstrap anyway- i will just try it..

Comment: My suggestion is learn to use plugins, of course don't go overboard with them, but if you are pretty much making them same thing again from scratch you might as well use the plugin as it will save you lots and lots of time. Also if this answered your question please mark it as answered.

Comment: i ve been trying to get the plugin working the entire day.. and it just wont fire. - even if I use the original code. I dont know what i make wrong.. does anybody here has a html how to use the bootsrtap 3 lightbox??? - joshhunt, I will mark it.. did not know that s possible. thy

Comment: No worries, there should be a dotted tick right next to the up and down arrows next to my answer. In regards to your previous answer, are there any javascript errors coming up? What is happening/not happening. You can also find me on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign